# jquery.tappable.js stops setInterval after tap

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I want to call a function every two seconds. I tried with setInterval(myFunction, 2000); and it worked, but:

I also have some tappable elements in the page.

```
$('div.square').tappable(function () { ... etc.
```

As soon as I tap on a tappable element, everything stops. myFunction is not called anymore. As if setInterval has stopped.

I don't understand the execution flow, I'm new to javascript and I don't understand what is happening.

this is the code I'm working with: https://github.com/jeffehobbs/HTML5-bingo/blob/master/js/script.js

How should I execute a function there on regular intervals, (to show the bingo numbers being drawn) and also be able to tap the bingo squares?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure myFunction isn't called anymore? Try to create a console log in myFunction to see if it is still called.

```
function myFunction() {
     console.log("I am called");
}
```

Comment: yes it is still called, I will create another question then, something different is happening. thanks!